# Back top top button

Tags: html, button

I am trying to create a back to top button for my website.

what exactly does the following do cause it is not working:

```
body[data-smooth-scrolling="1"] #to-top {
    right: 33px;
}
```

Comment: It targets the #to-top element in a body with the attribute of data-smooth-scrolling="1". It aligns the element 33 pixel from the right of its container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Sebsemillia's answer, adding the following to `<head>` should animate the scroll to top: (assuming jQuery is loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
        var anchor = $('#'+this.href.split('#')[1]);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: anchor.offset().top},'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple "to top" functionality, do the following:

1.) Add a target ID to an element on the top of your HTML, like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="ToTopTarget">
       content
    </div>
</body>
```

2.) Add an anchor link to target this:

```
<a href="#ToTopTarget">Back To Top</a>
```

All in all you have this example code:

```
<body>
    <div id="ToTopTarget">
       content
    </div>
    <a href="#ToTopTarget">Back To Top</a>
</body>
```

If you want the functionality of your example described, look at the explanation of  Huangism.